# Oauth 2.0 : Accessing asset in google map engine

Tags: google-maps, google-app-engine, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I tried invoking an Ajax GET method to access an asset - a google map Engine asset I created, given an Asset ID.

```
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/assets/0773289246413284785416071188762309719429',
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

But this doesn't work, and an error :

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/assets/07732892464132847854-16071188762309719429?_=1406257065386 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Says it's unauthorized. I tried testing the GET asset in google [Asset](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/reference/v1/assets/get), using the Asset ID, when I execute. It says:

```
This method requires you to be authenticated. You may need to activate the toggle above to authorize your request using OAuth 2.0.
```

I can test the GET asset there, by providing OAuth there. But How do I do this in my application? How do I provide OAuth 2.0 authentication so that I can access the assets? Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is OAuth2 Authorization. Firstly you need to get an oauth token and then put it in your reuest.

[Here is a guide for your reference](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/oauth/). I think the guide is detailed and it contains sample code, so just follow it.